# How to send simple one line emails on macOS from command line to/from gmail?

Tags: terminal, command-line, mail.app, email, gmail

My need is simple, I want something with this functionality:

```
echo 'hello' | mail -s 'test' xxx@icloud.com
```

The above currently works and  `mail` is able to send to an icloud email and sends via some network, domain email that my college uses. If I attempt to send to my own `gmail` account, I get: "Undelivered Mail Returned to Send" and:

```
 Our system has
    detected that this 550-5.7.1 message does not meet IPv6 sending guidelines
    regarding PTR records 550-5.7.1 and authentication. Please review 550-5.7.1
    https://support.google.com/mail/?p=IPv6AuthError for more information 550
    5.7.1 .
```

I'm not sure how to fix this. I'd also like to send from my own `gmail` or other account and configure it so.

Comment: You're running into spam blocking, since you're sending from an untrusted IP address. You probably need to either set it up to relay outgoing messages through your local ISP, or authenticate to google (or whatever server you're sending to/through). This is all rather difficult, because it needs to be difficult for spammers to do.

Comment: This is answered here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/444382/send-email-from-command-line-macos-monterey-12-3 describing some changes to `/etc/postfix/main.cf` which worked. Adapt this to your specific needs.

Comment: Depending on why you are doing this, you might well look for a question dealing with  using AppleScript to send a message via your Apple Mail.